# Apache kafka 2.0.0 version - Connection to node 1 failed authentication due to: SSL handshake

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I'm using kafka version kafka_2.12-2.0.0 and received the below error after enabling SSL authentication. It seems to be working fine with previous versions: kafka_2.12-1.1.0, 2.11-0.10.2.2 etc.

I don't understand why it is not working with latest version 2.11-0.2.0.0? Has anyone observed the same issue that I'm facing right now with 2.0.0 version.

Below is my test environment docker config file.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSl://:9093
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/server.keystore
ssl.keystore.password=<Key store password>
ssl.key.password = <private key password>
ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/truststore.keystore
ssl.truststore.password=<trust store password>
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
```

And here's the error:

```
[2018-10-01 09:33:38,984] ERROR [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Please include the error you are receiving.

Comment: hi, below is the error .. [2018-10-01 09:33:38,984] ERROR [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Connection to node 1 failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Answer (score 17):

Without more details it's hard to tell for sure, but 2.0.0 introduced a change of behaviour related to the handling of SSL connections.

As mentioned in the [2.0.0 upgrade notes](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_200_notable), the broker setting `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm` is now set to `https`. This enforces hostname verification to prevent "man-in-the-middle" attacks.

To restore previous behaviour, you need to explicitely set this to an empty string.

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to fix it... now it is resolved.

Comment: If it solved your issue, feel free to vote and accept the answer!

Comment: i did `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=""` but still recieive the same error message in the log.

Comment: It's `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=`, no double quotes.

Comment: Confirmed Confluent latest docker image has the same thing as well. According to Confluent doc, https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html#optional-settings, it says Kafka now verify the SSL cert hostname. It will fail if your cert sign with hostname that doesn't match the target.

Comment: I have set ```ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=``` and the problem still happens. Initally, both external and inter-broker connection are failed. After i set above setting to empty string, the inter-broker connection is well but the external connection still get the output:

```ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)```

Kafka version: 2.4.1

Can anyone give me an advice :D

Answer (score 0):

Was also facing a similar issue. My issue, I was having Kafka server 1.1.1 running and was using Kafka client 2.1.0 to push records. Changing Kafka client to 1.1.1 solved my issue.

Hope this helps.