# How to use Kafka with TLS peer verification turned off

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, tls1.2

I'm testing kafka cluster creation using let's encrypt staging certs. After creating, on my machine, I run the kafka-provided `kafka-console-consumer.sh` and `kafka-console-producer.sh` scripts. When I ran with let's encrypt production, it worked fine. But now that I'm using staging certs, I get this when I run the producer:

```
ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (2.kafka.mysite.com/10.1.17.191:9092) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I use these properties for producer script:

```
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="kafka" password="secret";
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

I'd like to give the option to ignore TLS, and I'd like it to be some parameter I can toggle (on the cluster or on the client) to allow it. How can I achieve this? For anyone familiar with Rabbitmq, I think it's similar to VERIFY_PEER=false, aka VERIFY_NONE.

Comment: Just curious, does your TLS-enabled listener still use port 909**2**, as shown in your message `Connection to node -1 (2.kafka.mysite.com/10.1.17.191:9092...`? Also, what kafka version you're on?

Comment: @mazaneicha Yes, the server config has `listeners: "SASL_SSL://0.0.0.0:9092"` and also `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: ""`. kafa version = 2.2.0

Comment: So I assume you saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52590351/apache-kafka-2-0-0-version-connection-to-node-1-failed-authentication-due-to. What happens if you leave blank after `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm:  `  (remove `""`)?

Comment: Sorry for posting it like that: it is indeed a blank string in the final configuration. That's just how I have it set up with Ansible, but once it gets put into the configuration via a template, it is an empty string. @mazaneicha

Comment: Have you tried testing connection using something like `openssl s_client -showcerts -debug -connect <host:port>`?

Comment: Yeah, and I see that `issuer=/CN=Fake LE Intermediate X1`. So I expect that. I'd like to know how to configure kafka to not worry about certs, but still use encryption in transit.

Answer (score 2):

The kafka configuration has setting

> ssl.client.auth

Its value could be set as required,requested or none. You could set it to requested.his means client authentication is optional. unlike requested , if this option is set client can choose not to provide authentication information about itself

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have already tried setting `ssl.client.auth=none` and that did not change the issue. I have also tried using PLAIN/PLAINTEXT for these fields: `advertised.listeners`, `listeners`, `inter.broker.listener.name`, `sasl.enabled.mechanisms`, and `sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol`.

Comment: That changed my error to: `WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (2.kafka.mysite.com/10.1.2.3:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)` I'm positive the error isn't from #2 or #3, and even though I disabled it, I know I'm sending the right username/password.

Comment: @swagrov Did you find any remedy for this warning?

Comment: I have the same issue. how Did you solve it?